# Taxonomy Menu - Making High-Level Pages Display Something Different To Lowest Level Pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm fairly new to Drupal so please bear with me if I use dodgy terminology or ask something that seems really stupid!  I have looked through the posts on StackExchange and several other websites but still cannot find an answer to my problem.

I have created a Product Group/Product hierarchy structure in Taxonomy.  It may consist of several level of sub-groups until it gets to the child product.  For example:

- Kitchenware

  - Saucepans

    - Aluminium
    - Cast Iron
  - Frying Pans

    - Omelette Pans
    - Woks
  - Utensils

Using Taxonomy Menu & Views I can get the menu to either:
  (1) Display empty pages for each of the product groups which have no products (i.e. only contain sub-product groups) & then the lowest level product group shows all products that it contains.  So Kitchenware & Frying Pans return empty pages and Woks displays all woks.

***or***

(2) Each level of the tree shows all of the products in that product group and all of the products in any subordinate groups. For example, Frying Pans will show all products linked to Frying Pans, plus any products in omelette pans and woks.

What I would like is either one of the following:
(1) Not display any page for higher level Product Groups (i.e. make them unselectable) and show product details only on bottom-level groups (e.g. Woks).

***OR***
(2) Each Product Group shows a list of links to sub-groups that it contains, and then the lowest level group shows details of the products within it.

I have spent many hours trying many different approaches but have not found an answer.  I do not know PHP so I would prefer not to have to try and modify code modules if I can avoid it.

I would be really grateful if someone can help me with this or suggest an alternative approach to what I want to see.

Regards,

Paul